# Unable to store value in mongodb with node red

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node-red

I have a simple workflow on node red shown on the image [image]

I created the collection mesures in the database weather with Robo T3 (previously robomongo) with the following parameters :
[image]

note that "auto index _id" is ticked.

However, when I try to insert a value in this database I get the error

```
"TypeError: Cannot create property '_id' on string '{"test":"msg"}'"
```

I haven't got a clue why I cannot insert a value in my mondo database.

I'm running the mongo server ( version 2.4.14 ) and red node on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Does someone has any insight ?

Comment: Looks like you need to turn the string into an `Object` first.

Comment: Actually I followed a tutorial where the author did exactly the same workflow. here is the link : https://youtu.be/mnfJwwFXzng that's in French but you can look at his workflow thought. He's using the same version of mongodb as me

Comment: The workflow you show above doesn't look at all like the one from the tutorial. There's in fact a crucial step missing: turning the string into an `Object`. I assume that is what the `json` node does.

Comment: Here's a demo showing the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/uzuca9qa/ (check the browser's console)

Comment: Apparently developing after 2am is not a good thing… I wasn't able to see that I missed the Json block. I feel a bit ashamed to see that it was that simple. Thanks for helping me out Chris !

Comment: No need for a JSON node, the inject node can be set to inject a JSON object directly

Comment: Also if you add the "solution" as a proper answer we can mark this question as answered